# how to display datas from store?

Tags: sqlite, sencha-touch

> hai all,
>   i want to display datas from json store without using list....
>   then in url i want increment the page number...
>   i have following code in jsonstore....

```
    Ext.regModel('message',{fields:['Drugid','Drugname','Manufacturer','Price','Unit','Catid']});

var store=new Ext.data.Store({

model: 'message',

proxy: {
type: 'ajax',
url: 'http://174.36.149.186/Medical/api/drugapi.php?op=mdrug&page=1',---- here i give just page is one,i want increment the page number

reader: {
type: 'json',
root: 'result.message'
}
},
autoLoad: true

});
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. How do you want to display you data if not in a List ?

Comment: can show in alert...because i want insert that json store datas into new sqlite table

Answer (score 0):

i'm also new to sencha but maybe you could define an item template and add the template to a view just as you would eg. a textbox. the item template is declared just like an object and then passed to the view as the value of the itemtpl config attribute. 
http://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2/